# split index of tuples into multindex pandas dataframe - using python

Tags: python, pandas, tuples

I created a dataframe from a list of dataframes like this:

```
team_df = pd.concat(all_teams, keys=flat_list, axis=0)
```

I attached a picture of the output.

I want to convert
[image]

it to is something like this:

team1

```
player 1
player 2
player 3
player 4
player 5
player 6
```

team2

```
player 1
player 2
player 3
player 4
player 5
player 6
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples` to set index.

```
In [1045]: df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.index, names=['team', 'player'])

In [1046]: df
Out[1046]:
             d
team player
1    2       1
     3       2
2    3       3
```